# Given: $ f(x,y) = \frac{xy \sin x}{x^2+y^2} $, find $\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial \phi}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Given:
>
> $$ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{xy \sin x}{x^2+y^2}  & (x,y) \neq (0,0),\\  0  & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{matrix} \right. $$
>
> and let $\phi =(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ be the unit vector.
>
> Find $$\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial \phi}$$

When $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =-\dfrac{y\left(\left(x^2-y^2\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\left(-x^3-y^2x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{x\sin\left(x\right)\left(y^2-x^2\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2}$$

When $(x,y) = (0,0)$

$$D_{U(\phi)} f(x,0) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+ t\phi_1,0+ t\phi_2) -f(x,0)}{t} $$

Reediting my understanding.

Much appreciated for your input/help.

Comment: $f(0,0)$ is a constant, it's derivative is therefore 0

Comment: @TehRod. Although he writes $\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial \phi}$ he surely means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a two-dimensional environment you should not use the letter $\phi$ as variable for a unit vector, since $\phi$ is reserved for the polar or some similar angle (hence  more or less a real variable). More serious is my following complaint: There is no such thing as ${\partial f\over\partial\phi}$ (*your* vector $\phi$) since you cannot divide by  vectors, let alone take the limit of such  quotients. Nevertheless, the idea of "directional derivative" of a given function $f$ at some point $(x,y)$ in the direction of a given unit vector makes sense.

For $\phi\in{\mathbb R}$ you can define the unit vector ${\bf u}(\phi):=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ and then consider the *directional derivative* of $f$ at some point $(x,y)$ in direction ${\bf u}(\phi)$. This directional derivative $D_{{\bf u}(\phi)}f(x,y)$ is given by
$$D_{{\bf u}(\phi)}f(x,y)=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot{\bf u}(\phi)$$ at all points $(x,y)$ where $f$ is differentiable. In the example at hand this is the case at all points $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.

At points ${\bf z}=(x,y)$ where $f$ is not differentiable we can still ask for directional derivatives by looking at the limit
$$D_{{\bf u}(\phi)}f({\bf z}):=\lim_{t\to0+}{f\bigl({\bf z}+t{\bf u}(\phi)\bigr)-f({\bf z})\over t}\ .\tag{1}$$
As an example, the function $f({\bf z}):=|{\bf z}|$ has directional derivative $1$  in all directions at ${\bf z}={\bf 0}$.

Now $(0,0)$ is a special point for the $f$ defined in the question. Putting ${\bf z}={\bf 0}$ in $(1)$ we obtain
$$D_{{\bf u}(\phi)}f({\bf 0})=\lim_{t\to0+}{t^2\cos\phi\sin\phi\sin(t\cos\phi)\over t^3}=\cos^2\phi\sin\phi\ ,$$
using Hopital's rule.

Comment: You can define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$ to be the vector that satisfies
$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \cdot \frac{d\phi}{dt}.$

Comment: +1 for recalling that the formula relating directional derivatives and gradient is true at points where the function is differentiable.

Comment: @christianblatter thx for the extensive explanation. What would the justification be (or the process thinking) leading to want to change the original unit vector $\phi=(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ into $u(\phi)= (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$? Don't we have already a unit vector?